# jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 3.0.0, I try to use query.executeUpdate() method in my service.

There is the code of my service:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.persistence.Query;
import jakarta.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import myRepositoriesPackage.PassageRepository;


@Service
public class PassageSevice {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private PassageRepository passageRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void UpdatePassageByNiveau(int niveau, String cin) {
        String queryRecherche = "UPDATE Passage p SET p.dateDebut = 
                 + " p.dateDebut + 1 year, "
                + "p.dateFin = p.dateFin + 1 year WHERE resident.cin = :cin 
                 + "  and p.niveau = :niveau ";
        Query query = em.createQuery(queryRecherche);
        query.setParameter("cin", cin);
        query.setParameter("niveau", niveau);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

I read that to use query.executeUpdate() method I have to add the annotation **@Transactional** from **org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional**. But it didn't work, and i steal have this error : `jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query|`.

Comment: You probably want to use `jakarta.transaction.Transactional` or even `javax.transaction.Transactional` instead

Comment: There is too little information here. How is this method being called? Where is this method defined, what does your configuration look like. Please add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet, the full stacktrace provides valuable information.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer i tried `jakarta.transaction.Transactional` but didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error typically occurs when we're trying to perform a database operation that modifies the database without a transaction.

The obvious solution is to wrap any database-modifying operation in a transaction:

```
Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
Query query
  = session.createQuery("UPDATE Passage p SET p.dateDebut = p.dateDebut + 1 year, "
            + "p.dateFin = p.dateFin + 1 year WHERE resident.cin = :cin and p.niveau = :niveau ");
    query.setParameter("cin", cin);
    query.setParameter("niveau", niveau);
updateQuery.executeUpdate();
txn.commit();
```

In the code snippet above, we manually initiate and commit the transaction. Although in a Spring Boot environment, we can achieve this by using the `@Transactional` annotation.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class FooService {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Adding  `@Transactional`  to the hole Service ( after @Service) save the problem. Before i use the  `@Transactional`  annotation just for the specific method that use  `.executeUpdate();`

Comment: If it was solved by annotating the class that means your method invocation was an internal one (from the same service) else it would have worked. Now the outer method is transactional (not that that is bad but it means you need to learn something about transactional boundaries).